# Lumen doesn't return data when of all countries

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Am trying to get list of all countries in lumen api but when i return all the data like this

```
 echo json_encode([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $results
        ]);
or

 return json_encode([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $results
        ]);

or

 return response([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $results
        ]);

i just get nothing no data no error
```

i only get data when i limit(15)

here is my function to get the list of countries

```
        $output = [];
        $database = \DB::table('country_t')
            ->select(['nameX3'])->get();

        foreach ($database as $item) {
            $name = $item->nameX3;
            $toLowerCase = strtolower(trim($name));
            $urlName = str_replace(' ', '-', $toLowerCase);

            $output[] = [
                'name' => $item->nameX3,
                'url' => $urlName . '-simcards',
            ];
        }

        return response([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $output
        ]);
```

So this function does not return anything except when i `dd($output); or limit(15)`

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried with `return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data' => $output]);`?

Comment: Is your method a controller method? Or is it defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @porloscerros Ψ comment, I was able to get an error at least.
After I used `return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data' => $output]);` I got an error saying `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`.

Issue is the data that is being encoded by `json_encode` contains even non-utf8 characters such as Russian words, etc.

To solve this issue I created a function that will encode this data using **mb_convert_encoding**, so I also had to make it handle even multidimensional array

```
    function toUTF8( $mixed ) {
        if (is_array($mixed)) {
            foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
                $mixed[$key] = toUTF8($value);
            }
        } elseif (is_string($mixed)) {
            return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
        }
        return $mixed;
    }

  Then calling the function 

  $this->toUTF8($output);
```

All in all if you have data that contains non-utf8 characters, you must encode the data.